# Finding moment of inertia of circular sector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a question from my multivariable calculus class. Let D be a circular sector $0\le r \le a$, $0 \le \theta \le \pi / 3$

Find the moment of inertia of D with respect to the y-axis. Assume uniform density.

So far, I've parametrized the circle as: 
$r(t) = a \cos\theta i + a \sin\theta j$

And I know I need to use the integral $I_y = \int (x^2 + z^2) \delta s$

This next step is where I'm stuck. I know I need to calculate 
I calculate $\lvert v(t)\rvert$ but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $y$ as a function of $x$ over the range $[0,a]$ to get
$I_y = \rho \int_0^a x^2 y(x) dx$.

You will need to split the integration range into $[0,\cos {\pi \over 3}]$ and
$[\cos {\pi \over 3}, a]$ as you have
$y(x) = \begin{cases} x \tan {\pi \over 3}, & x \in [0,\cos {\pi \over 3}] \\
\sqrt{a^2-x^2}, & x \in [\cos {\pi \over 3}, a] \end{cases}$.